# Canvas arc and fill with gradient

Tags: html, canvas

I have the following source code:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="main" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function myRnd(val)
{
    return parseInt(Math.random() * val);
}

function rndCircles() {
    var maxCircles = 30;

    for (var r = 1; r <= maxCircles; r++) {
        var c = document.getElementById("main");
        var x = myRnd(c.clientWidth);
        var y = myRnd(c.clientHeight);
        var radius = parseInt(Math.random() * 30);

        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        // Create gradient
        var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(75, 50, 5, 90, 60, 100);
        grd.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(' + myRnd(255) + ', ' + myRnd(255) + ',' + myRnd(255) + ')');
        grd.addColorStop(1, 'white');

        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI,false);
        // Fill with gradient
        ctx.fillStyle = grd;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        //ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

rndCircles();
```

I cannot see each arc filled with a different color/gradient on Chrome. Why? Am I missing something?

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/j9wst2yd/

Comment: I doubt this issue is limited to chrome. See the docs for createRadialGradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient will use the initial position and radius when defined, which means the arcs further away from it will eventually turn completely white (or whatever the outer color would be).

You can solve this by using *translation* instead of setting position for the arcs.

**Only a couple of adjustments are needed -**

Create the gradient based around origin (0, 0):

```
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 100);
// ...
```

Then replace setting arc position with translation, here absolute using `setTransform()` instead (`translate()` would accumulate, forcing you to reverse the translation afterwards which is more performance costly):

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, x, y);               // two last = translation
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI,false);   // draw at origin
```

To reset back to normal (identity matrix) just set (0,0) for `setTransform()`:

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Adjust as needed.

```js
function myRnd(val)
{
    return parseInt(Math.random() * val);
}
function rndCircles() {
    var maxCircles = 30;
 var c = document.getElementById("main");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 
    for (var r = 1; r <= maxCircles; r++) {
        var x = myRnd(c.clientWidth);
        var y = myRnd(c.clientHeight);
        var radius = parseInt(Math.random() * 30);

  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, radius);
  grd.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(' + myRnd(255) + ', ' + myRnd(255) + ',' + myRnd(255) + ')');
  grd.addColorStop(1, 'white');
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;

        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);
     ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI,false);
        // Fill with gradient
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        //ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
rndCircles();
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: great! only one problem... after drawing circles in your way i cannot see anymore another line: ctx.moveTo(xNew, yNew);  ctx.lineTo(toX, toY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.stroke();

Comment: @S.P. you didn't have any line in the original question, neither the fiddle. This info should be included from the beginning. The answer solves the problem as described in the question. You can do two passes, draw the lines as normal with the code you have, then draw the arcs on top. You need to store each positions so make an array with random positions, draw lines, then arcs.

Comment: i marked the question as solved. thank you for your kind attention and time. if you want you can take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/j9wst2yd/2/  i think thats a relative coords or similar problem... i dont understand.... sorry. i need to start drawing after circles in the middle of canvas, at 250,250. thank you again.

Comment: what i was looking for is: ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);